# SimplePanel and child widgets

Tags: gwt

I have a question about the SimplePanel and its child widgets. I am catching the following Exception

```
SimplePanel can contain one child widget
```

In my code, the unique element that inherits from the SimplePanel is a ScrollPanel which is used as follows:

```
scroll = new ScrollPanel();
scroll.add(internalVerticalPanel);
internalVerticalPanel2.add(scroll);
```

The "internalVerticalPanel" object is composed by an HorizontalPanel and Labels. Is it not possible this combination?

Thank you very much in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just as the exception says - you can add only one child to the `SimplePanel` container (and its subclasses, like `ScrollPanel` or `FormPanel`). The stacktrace from the exception should pinpoint the place where the second child is getting added.

As for the second part of your question - the (one) child of `SimplePanel` can have multiple children itself (if its implementation allows it). So the code you've shown us should work as you expected - it's the code you have not shown us that's misbehaving ;)

This is OK:

```
Whatever container
|_ ScrollPanel
   |_FlowPanel  <- the only direct child of ScrollPanel
     |_SimplePanel
     |_TextBox
     |_ScrollPanel
     |_FlowPanel
     |_ScrollPanel
```

This seems to be your situation:

```
ScrollPanel
|_ChildWidget1 <- child number 1 of ScrollPanel
| |_TextBox
| |_TextBox
| |_Label
|_ChildWidget2 <- child number 2 of ScrollPanel -> error!
```

It's OK for `ChildWidget1` to have multiple children (as long as it supports multiple children - for example, it's a `FlowPanel`). It's an erro for `ScrollPanel` to have more than one *direct* child: `ChildWidget1` *and* `ChildWidget2`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!! The code created two ScrollPanel objects (it was replicated in another part of the code) and I have removed the second object, keeping a single Scroll containing a higher level of objects and it works. Then, I guess, a single object of the Scroll can be created, not only a single child, right?

Comment: Without seeing the exact code it's hard to say what happened but I'm *sure* you *can* create multiple instances of `ScrollPanel` (or other `SimplePanel`s). Just make sure that every instance has only *one* **direct** child. I'll add some examples to my answer.

Comment: That was not exactly what I did. I created one object ScrollPanel panel = new ScrollPanel(); with its unique child. Once inserted into the main screen I created a new object (i.e. scroll = new ScrollPanel()) and the same procedure than before. Here, the code is broken...Now, I have a single object in all the code and it works!! Thanks!